# Why isn't my equation rendering in RPubs?

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, equation

I have a slide with the following code in RPresenter:

```
    The Math and Code behind it
    ===
    * The application is instantly calculating the monthly payment via the following formula:  

$$(\text{Principal})\frac{(\text{Interest rate})(1+\text{interest rate})^\text{Term}}{(1+\text{interest rate})^\text{Term}-1}$$  

 * **Principal** refers to the amount left after the downpayment (which is usually expressed as a percentage of the cost)
       * **Term** is the amount of time to pay the mortgage, usually 15 to 30 years
```

The equation code

```
$$(\text{Principal})\frac{(\text{Interest rate})(1+\text{interest rate})^\text{Term}}{(1+\text{interest rate})^\text{Term}-1}$$
```

renders just fine in RStudio, but when I publish the presentation to RPubs it does not convert it to an equation. The LaTeX is just displayed as text.

Any idea of how to fix this? Here is the rendered presentation: http://rpubs.com/vashts85/76316

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the opening `$$` by `$$latex`. Quoting from the RPubs documentation for [*MathJax and Writing Equations*](https://rpubs.com/gallery/equations):

> To display an equation and place it on its own line (centered), use two dollar signs such as:
>
> `$$latex equation $$`
>
> For example, to display the Taylor Series nicely:
>
> [ f(a) + \frac{f'(a)}{1!} (x-a) + \frac{f''(a)}{2!} (x-a)^{2} + \frac{f'''(a)}{3!} (x-a)^{3} + \ldots ]
>
> Enter the following:
>
> ```
> $$latex
> f(a) + \frac{f'(a)}{1!} (x-a) + \frac{f''(a)}{2!} (x-a)^{2} + \frac{f'''}{3!} (x-a)^{3} + \ldots
> $$
> ```

Comment: Now I get the following error when trying to update it:

Error in readBin(conn, what = "raw", n = contentLength) : 
  invalid 'n' argument
Calls: rpubsUpload ... uploadFunction -> readResponse -> rawToChar -> readBin
Execution halted

Any ideas?

Comment: Also this solution does not work, I still get the same issue even though the equation is valid Latex